# restatement of almost sure convergence for a sequence of random variables

Tags: real-analysis, probability, probability-theory, analysis, measure-theory

Let $X(t), t\geq0$ be a sequence of random variable such that
$$
\limsup_{t\rightarrow \infty} |X(t)| =0,\quad a.s.
$$

Then, can we say that for any $\epsilon>0$ there exists $T>0$ such that
$$
|X(t)|< \epsilon, \quad a.s.
$$
for $t\geq T$?

If not, what is the counterexample? and What condition is required to say the above statement?

Answer (score 2):

This is not true. Consider $\Omega:=(0,1]$ with $\Bbb P:=\,$Lebesgue measure on $(0,1]$,  and $$X(t;\omega)=\begin{cases}(1+t)\omega,&\text{if $\omega\le \frac1{1+t}$,}\\[.4em]0,&\text{otherwise.}\end{cases}$$
Then for any $\epsilon\in(0,1)$, $|X(t)|>\epsilon$ as soon as $\omega\in(\frac\epsilon{1+t},\frac1{1+t}]$, so with probability $\frac{1-\epsilon}{1+t}$. Thus it cannot exist $T>0$ such that $\sup_{t\ge T}|X(t)|\le\epsilon$ holds almost surely.

However, we do have that for each $\omega\in\Omega$, $|X(t;\omega)|=0$ as soon as $t>T(\omega):=\frac1\omega-1$, so $$\limsup_{t\to\infty}|X(t)|=0,\qquad\text{a.s.}$$
The issue here is that the threshold $T$ is **random** and explodes as $\omega$ approaches $0$. Having it uniformly bounded in $\omega$ (almost surely) amounts to requiring convergence with respect to the [essential supremum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Essential_infimum_and_essential_supremum).

Comment: Thank you very much your answer. I have searched essential supremum and found that $ess sup f \leq sup f $. Then, $\lim sup|X(t)|=0$ is enough to guarantee that $\lim essup|X(t)|=0$, which is what you said (convergence with respect to the essential supremum)?

Comment: You seem to be confusing $\lim\limits_{t\to\infty}\sup\limits_{\omega\in\Omega}|X(t;\omega)|=0$ with $\limsup\limits_{t\to\infty}|X(t;\omega)|=0$ a.s. The former is stronger.